# Android accessibility service detect notification

Tags: android, notifications, accessibility

I'm trying to make my app detect whenever a notification is displayed. I've enabled it in the settings app and `onServiceConnected` does get called, however when I create a notification or receive an e-mail through the gmail app nothing happens, `onAccessibilityEvent` does not get called.

Android manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.slide"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
<application android:label="Slide"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Settings"
        android:label="Slide">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Tools"
        android:label="Slide"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".LocalService"/>
    <service android:name=".NotificationService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
        android:label="Slide"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

NotificationService.java

```
package com.test.slide;

import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;

public class NotificationService extends AccessibilityService {
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    System.out.println("onAccessibilityEvent");
    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED) {
        System.out.println("notification: " + event.getText());
    }
}
@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    System.out.println("onServiceConnected");
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED;
    info.notificationTimeout = 100;
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityEvent.TYPES_ALL_MASK;
    setServiceInfo(info);
}

@Override
public void onInterrupt() {
    System.out.println("onInterrupt");
}
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you found the solution? i have exactly the same problem.

Comment: For what system version are you programming? ICS? jelly bean?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Accessibility services in Android 4.0 and above can behave strangely if there is no [accessibility-service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AccessibilityService) meta-data tag defined in the manifest. Try defining the meta-data as in the examples below. You should continue to use setServiceInfo() to maintain backward compatibility with pre-4.0 devices.

Also, I would recommend specifying a feedback type that is specific to your service, rather than using "all".

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <service
        . . .
        android:name=".NotificationService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/accessibilityservice" />
    </service>
```

**res/xml/accessibilityservice.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeNotificationStateChanged"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:notificationTimeout="100" />
```

There was an error in your feedbackType. Corrected below. Still, consider using a more specific feedback type.

**NotificationService.java**

```
@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED;
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_ALL_MASK;
    info.notificationTimeout = 100;
    setServiceInfo(info);
}
```

Comment: Now you are defining the `serviceInfo` in XML and code. You may leave out the code part of AccessibilityServiceInfo because the xml is defined in the manifest.

Comment: On the contrary, you must define it in both places for compatibility with pre-ICS devices.

Comment: @alanv I've done all what you said, still onServiceConnected() is not getting called, and o course performGlobalAction returns false, what should I consider more? knowing that I enabled my service under mobile settings -> Accesibility

Comment: @Astrount.. could you find the reason for your problem? Even for me, onServiceConnected is not called though I am doing everything

Answer (score 4):

The app using AccessibilityService needed to have a permission from settings>Accessibility in order to access the system events.
Allow permission from settings . This may work

check this link

[accessibility service is not started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087758/accessibility-service-is-not-started)

Comment: thanks i tried every thing but i have to enable it from settings