# getting the Notifications in 4.1 and above in android

Tags: android, android-service

How to get the notifications in android using Accessibility Service above 4.0?

Why `onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event)` not calling When Notification fired above 4.0
Please give Proper Suggestion

Thanks in advance

```
@Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

        final int eventType = event.getEventType();
        System.out.println("MyServ.onAccessibilityEvent()");
        switch (eventType) {
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Notification fired",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Type is Announcement",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
```

In `onServiceConnected()`

```
@Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
        info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED;
        info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_SPOKEN;
        setServiceInfo(info);
}
```

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554448/android-accessibility-service-detect-notification

Comment: calling Broadcast is more than one time?? how can i control that @androiduser

Comment: calling Broadcast is more than one time?? What does that mean?? I guess you are trying to say that your BroadCast receiver is getting called multiple times...

Comment: yes when i get the event from accessibility event i want to call Broadcast Receiver @androiduser

Comment: Do you want to show Notification in your status bar of device when your "accessibility event" is called ??

Comment: yes i want those notifications which shown in the status bar

Comment: Check my answer in answer's section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
    private void generateNotification(Context context, String message,
        long when, String query) {

    int icon = R.drawable.icon;
         long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String appname = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    Notification notification;

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            intent, 0);

        if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, appname, message,
                    contentIntent);
            notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notificationManager.notify((int) when, notification);

        } else {
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    context);
            notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(appname).setWhen(when)
                    .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(appname)
                    .setContentText(message).build();

            notificationManager.notify((int) when, notification);

        }

}
```

You can call `generateNotification()` method in `onAccessibilityEvent()` and notifications will be displayed.

Comment: your answer working fine but when i got  any message or call,In the Notification status bar multiple notifications showing.It should display single notification per single event @androiduser

Comment: For single notification you should use : notificationManager.notify(0, notification); instead of notificationManager.notify((int) when, notification);