# Android KK Accessibility service app example

Tags: android, accessibility, android-4.4-kitkat, android-a11y

I have been searching around to integrate an accessibility service into my application to allow software simulated keypresses of back and recent.

I have followed the official android accessibility docs and have included an XML , accessibility class and ensured permissions and service/intents are correct
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html

I cannot currently post my code as I am on the road posting via my phone.

The project seems to compile but I cannot see my application show up in the accessibility settings section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12557839/2978914) i had the same problem as you and i managed to get it working.. as soon as i added the Java part to the service it began showing up in the settings!