# How to get info reg. notification active in status bar

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to read the notifications sitting in my status bar and based on the notification subject, i need to perform some action.
Is it possible?
If yes, please let me know..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with API 18 there is a [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) class.
You can use it to get the active notifications or get notified about new notifications.

On older android versions there is a hack with Accessibility Service.
Check out this answer: [Android accessibility service detect notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554448/android-accessibility-service-detect-notification)