# Android AccessibilityService on off status

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I am using **AccessibilityService** to monitor notifications. I followed [this](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087758/accessibility-service-is-not-started). Finally, it works and I get to know about new notifications.

But, to **Connect** the **AccessibilityService** I need to ask user to enable it from the **ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS**, which I do this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

But, the problem is I want to check if the user has enabled it (AccessibilityService) or not. Also, I don't what to ask users again to enable it if they have already enabled it. So, is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can test whether the user has enabled your Accessibility Service by checking the secure settings. `Settings.Secure.getString()` will give you a `:` separated list of enabled services, and you can check whether yours is in there. Something like this:

```
ComponentName compName = new ComponentName(context, MyAccessibilityService.class);
String flatName = compName.flattenToString();
String enabledList = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES);
boolean isEnabled = enabledList != null && enabledList.contains(flatName);
```